# Error while submission of "publish_actions" permission in facebook developer account

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

I have created facebook developer account last week.

I need to upload videos from android app to facebook page.

when i request to post videos using graph api it shows me publish_actions" error.
After research i found i haven't add this permission in my account.

I am trying to add "publish_actions" permission in my facebook developer account, but during submission it shows **"It looks like you haven't made any API requests to access content with the publish_actions permission in the last 30 days."**

[image]

Comment: So have you made any request using `publish_actions`?

Comment: no, i haven't made any request. can you provide steps to make request?

Comment: So thats what the warning is saying :)

Comment: ok, how can make request which removes this warning?

Comment: just make the request. How may i know what your app does? just publish  the post you want to while your  app in dev mode and then try to add the permissions in your settings

Comment: ok, i will do, thanks

Answer (score 1):

in order to try POST requests (with publish_permissions for example) you can do the following:
On facebook developer page,go to Graph API Explorer menu section (under Tools & Support).On the Graph API Explorer page, select your app  and try graph api post requests (selecting POST in request type) like publish, retrieve data and so on.

[image]

Comment: when i request from android app for publish message to my page it gives following error



My response 

{Response:  responseCode: 403, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 403, errorCode: 200, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action}, isFromCache:false}